How do I make a link when hovering over which a content window appears with text or links as in the site header menu?
Here is an example of such mechanics:
enter image description here
I tried to implement such mechanics, but there is a problem with the fact that when you hover over the link "Hello" a window appears with the links "Bye" and "See you soon" but when we hover over the links that are in the yellow square, they close and work intermittently, it is difficult to use. I can't find the error:


let linksTimeout;

    function showLinks(event) {
        let linksContainer = document.getElementById("linksContainer");
        linksContainer.style.display = "block";
        linksContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", () => clearTimeout(linksTimeout));
        linksContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
            linksTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                linksContainer.style.display = "none";
            }, 0);
        });
    }

    function hideLinks(event) {
        let linksContainer = document.getElementById("linksContainer");
        linksTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            linksContainer.style.display = "none";
        }, 0);
    }
        .container p {
            background: green;
            padding: 16px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .links-container {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        .links-container a {
            display: flex;
            background: yellow;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hover Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <p id="text" onmouseover="showLinks(event)" onmouseout="hideLinks(event)">hello</p>
    <div id="linksContainer" class="links-container">
        <a href="page1.html">Bye</a>
        <a href="page2.html">See you soon</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




It's just a simple div which is being set from display: none to display: {what they use flex or grid}.
display: none means the element is hidden.
And when this property  is changed from none,the element appears on the screen with the display pattern such as flex and grid.
It will be javascript allowing a trigger for every element in header of the navbar.

The element was at its initial state being hidden. And on hover on the link will cause that respective div to appear on screen.
Every link should had a separate div where the content of that specific link is placed.
Instead of  this, they can use this method by making a single div and then replacing the innerHtml with the respective link when the link is hovered.(This is the second method)

It could be simple (or maybe not). So, I suppose you want to activate the submenu when the user hovers over a menu option. So, the parent container needs to have a position: relative and the submenu one needs to have a position: absolute to get this overlapping effect.
But you might need VanillaJS to toggle the position property of each submenu element

Thanks for the answer, I would like you to help me find an error in my code, I just wanted to implement something like this simple window using the example image, but I don't understand why I have a square with links closing.

First of all, you're firing the same event for different elements to toggle the display property. So, keep in mind that when the container catches the hover event, the linkContainer's display property will be set to block. When the container's parent loses the hover, the linkContainer's display property will be set to none... Also the parent doesnt have relative position prop
